# Disabling a user's ability to change password on Active Directory

Tags: active-directory, ldap, python, password

We run a multi-directory environment (AD and OpenLDAP) and perform password synchronization via an internal webapp. This works well because we've disabled users from changing their own password via OpenLDAP and AD could only be accessed by the few services that require AD.

However, we are now looking into allowing PC's to attach to the AD domain. Initially, I believed that disabling password change for users would be as simple as changing the initial **userAccountControl** LDAP attribute we assign during account provisioning. This proved to not be as simple as I assumed.

We currently use Python and [python-ldap](http://www.python-ldap.org/) for account provisioning (code below), Per [Microsoft docs](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/305144), we set **userAccountControl** to 66048 (Normal account and don't expire password). I tried changing it to 66112 (66048 + Disable user password change) but AD did not retain that value and instead, recorded it as 66048.

Has anyone done something like this before? I'd prefer to accomplish it either by using Python or a set-it-and-forget-it setting on AD.

FYI: This is how the account provisioning Python code looks like right now:

```
import ldap

l = ldap.initialize(server)
l .simple_bind_s(admin_cn, admin_pass)

attributes = [
    ('displayName', login),
    ('sAMAccountName', login),
    ('cn', login),
    ('givenName', fn),
    ('sn', ln),
    ('name', full_name),
    ('userPrincipalName', '%s@example.com' % login),
    ('objectClass', ['person', 'top', 'organizationalPerson', 'user']),
    ('userAccountControl', '66048'), # <--- Line I thought I could change but not working as expected
    ('unicodePwd', encoded_password)
]

l.add_s(
    'cn=%s,ou=users,dc=example,dc=com' % login,
    attributes,
)
```

Comment: The following article might get me started. I will check it out at work on Tuesday. Too bad I cannot offer a bounty on this one heh: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa746398.aspx

Comment: Were you able to adapt your scripts to accommodate the procedure outlined in your above link?

Comment: I tested the script on one user and that did work. However, I wanted to see if anyone was aware of a configuration change that would disable password changing by default. Or, a Python solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not a Windows admin, but isn't this exactly the sort of thing that a Group Policy is for?  A brief Google search yields http://support.microsoft.com/kb/324744, which seems to do almost exactly what you want. This would be the "set-it-and-forget-it" model.

Also, [this](http://www.wisesoft.co.uk/scripts/vbscript_enable-disable_user_cannot_change_password.aspx) vbscripts purports to do what you want.

Comment: The Group Policy mentioned, while useful in some circumstances, only removes the ability to change one's own password from within the Windows GUI. It doesn't remove the ability to do so via scripting or any other method.

Comment: Huh.  Now I've learned something new.

Answer (score 2):

From the documents that you linked:

> PASSWD_CANT_CHANGE
>
> Note: You cannot assign this permission by directly modifying the UserAccountControl attribute. For information about how to set the permission programmatically, see the "Property flag descriptions" section.

And the property flag descriptions:

> PASSWD_CANT_CHANGE - The user cannot change the password. This is a permission on the user's object.

Or in other words, that specific bit in the bitmask cannot be set, and is returned after calculating the permissions on the user object.

Also linked from that document is http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa746398.aspx, which describes how to programatically adjust permissions on user objects.

What you're looking to do is deny the SELF pseudo-user access to change the password. The best way to do this would be configure permissions on an entire OU to restrict password changes. From here, move all of the relevant user objects into this OU and ensure that the user objects are inheriting their permissions from the OU.

If you're having issues with setting the security, ensure that you have Advanced Features enabled in ADUC (View --> Advanced Features).

Answer (score 0):

Similar to maniargaurav's solution, but you can do this programmatically using PowerShell (if it's Server 2008 R2 or using the Qwest AD cmdlets [link text](http://www.quest.com/powershell/activeroles-server.aspx)) or VBscript. If you're using Python now, you should have no issue enumerating all users and doing a script such as the following (from Scripting Guy at MS) [link text](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2004/12/02/how-can-i-prevent-a-local-user-from-changing-his-or-her-password.aspx).

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure how you can achieve this using program but in Active Directory User and Computers. Select User and go to properties. There is Option of "User cannot change password" option.

You can also check following URL if that would help:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms680832(VS.85).aspx

Comment: That's the whole point - the OP *doesn't want to have to do this* for each new user.